# Highcharts treemap data labels overflow

Tags: highcharts

while using Highcharts multi level treemap I ran into data labels overflow issue. Data labels overflows to other area. This works fine at level 1 & 2 when I use option *overflow: 'crop'* but does not work at level 3. Any idea where it is going wrong.

Here in example area with name:F data label overflows but data label with name:C at level 2 does not overflow.

[Here is fiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/LokeshKG/nvrjbc9o/).

```
$(function() {
var H = Highcharts;

$('#container').highcharts({

  chart: {
    type: 'treemap',
    width: 500
  },
  title: {
    text: null
  },
  plotOptions: {
    series: {
      layoutAlgorithm: 'stripes',
      alternateStartingDirection: true,
      levels: [{
        level: 1,
        dataLabels: {
          enabled: true,
          align: 'left',
          verticalAlign: 'top'
        }
      }, {
        level: 2,
        dataLabels: {
          formatter: function () {
            return this.point.realValue;
          },
          overflow: 'crop'
        }
      }, {
        level: 3,
        dataLabels: {
          formatter: function () {
            return this.point.realValue;
          },
          overflow: 'crop'
        }
      }]
    }
  },
  series: [{
    data: [{
      name: 'A',
      id: 'A',
      value: 1,
      color: '#FFFFFF'
    }, {
      name: 'B',
      id: 'B',
      value: 1,
      color: '#FFFFFF'
    }, {
      name: 'C',
      parent: 'A',
      id: 'A-1',
      value: 10,
      realValue: 'thisisveryveryveryveryveryverylongteststring',
      color: '#ECEA8E'
    }, {
      name: 'D',
      parent: 'A',
      id: 'A-2',
      color: '#FFFFFF'
    }, {
      name: 'E',
      parent: 'A-2',
      id: 'A-2-1',
      value: 10,
      realValue: 'A',
      color: '#599753'
    }, {
      name: 'F',
      parent: 'A-2',
      id: 'A-2-2',
      value: 10,
      realValue: 'thisisveryveryveryverylongteststring',
      color: '#1B3C40'
    }, {
      name: 'G',
      parent: 'B',
      id: 'B-1',
      value: 10,
      realValue: 'A',
      color: '#ECEA8E'
    }, {
      name: 'H',
      parent: 'B',
      id: 'B-2',
      color: '#FFFFFF'
    }, {
      name: 'I',
      parent: 'B-2',
      id: 'B-2-1',
      value: 10,
      realValue: 'A',
      color: '#599753'
    }, {
      name: 'J',
      parent: 'B-2',
      id: 'B-2-2',
      value: 10,
      realValue: 'A',
      color: '#1B3C40'
    }]
  }]
});
```

});

Comment: `overflow: 'crop'` is not mentioned in Highcharts API. Do you want to disable data label when it is wider than particular level od treemap chart?

Comment: I want to hide data label when they does not fit the point area and overflows to adjacent point area. Overflow: crop works fine with one point but not with the other. If you see the yellow area, it wirks fine.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, Highcharts doesn't hide labels when they don't fit `treemap` point area. As a workaround, you can loop through each data point and check if label related to it is wider. If it is wider just hide it.

Code:

```
chart: {
  type: 'treemap',
  width: 500,
  events: {
    load: function() {
      var chart = this,
        series = chart.series[0],
        pointWidth,
        labelWidth;

      series.data.forEach(function(point) {
        if (point.dataLabel) {
          pointWidth = point.shapeArgs.width;
          labelWidth = point.dataLabel.width;

          if (labelWidth > pointWidth) {
            point.dataLabel.hide();
          }
        }
      });
    }
  }
}
```

**Demo:** 
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/h65xm4qb/

**API reference:** 
https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGElement#hide